# i cant use the method setter setMarcaCelular on an array

Tags: java, arrays

i cant use the method setter setMarcaCelular on an array clientes[i]. i think the problem is the switch but i dont now why, im learning java so i lose my self quickly. this is my error. sry for my english is very bad.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at principal1.Principal1.main(Principal1.java:30)

```
package principal1;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import recursos.Cliente;

public class Principal1 {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int opc=0;
    int ventasLG=0;

    Cliente clientes[]=new Cliente[5];


    for (int i = 0; i < clientes.length; i++) {

        String nombre;
        String marcaCelular="";
        int celular=0;

        System.out.println("Ingrese marca del celular:\n1.-Nokia\n2.-Motorola"
                + "\n3.-LG\n4.-Kyocera");
        celular=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        switch(celular){
            case 1:
                clientes[i].setMarcaCelular("Nokia");
                System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del cliente");
                nombre=in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese cedula de identidad");
                int cedulaIdentidad=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Ingrese precio del celular");
                int precioCelular=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                clientes[i]=new Cliente(nombre, cedulaIdentidad, marcaCelular, precioCelular);
                  break;
            case 2:
                clientes[i].setMarcaCelular("Motorola");
                System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del cliente");
                nombre=in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese cedula de identidad");
                cedulaIdentidad=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Ingrese precio del celular");
                precioCelular=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                clientes[i]=new Cliente(nombre, cedulaIdentidad, marcaCelular, precioCelular);
                break;
            case 3:
                clientes[i].setMarcaCelular("LG");
                System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del cliente");
                nombre=in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese cedula de identidad");
                cedulaIdentidad=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Ingrese precio del celular");
                precioCelular=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                clientes[i]=new Cliente(nombre, cedulaIdentidad, marcaCelular, precioCelular);
                ventasLG++;
                break;
            case 4:
                clientes[i].setMarcaCelular("Kyocera");
                System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del cliente");
                nombre=in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese cedula de identidad");
                cedulaIdentidad=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Ingrese precio del celular");
                precioCelular=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                clientes[i]=new Cliente(nombre, cedulaIdentidad, marcaCelular, precioCelular);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Opcion incorrecta");
```

Comment: @B.M in java `Client[] clients` and `Client clients[]` are both valid for arrays

Comment: where did you fill the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating an array

```
 Cliente clientes[]=new Cliente[5];
```

doesnt mean there are already 5 instances of Cliente created and added to the array. You have to do it manually

```
Cliente clientes[]=new Cliente[5];
for (int i = 0; i < clientes.lenght; i++) {
    clientes[i] = new Cliente();
    // do whatever you want
}
```